# Get a value from struct inside list

Tags: elixir

I have a list as follows which has

```elixir
[
  %Photos{
    url: "http://localhost:4000/test/img",
    user: "localhost:4000/test/img/123"}]
```

How do I get the result as `"localhost:4000/test/img/123"` which is a string?

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello there, [Accessing and Updating](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/structs.html#accessing-and-updating-structs) structs are something you are searching but read the whole page it's useful to know more about structs, happy coding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the struct is under your control, you might implement [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html) for it and use [`get_in/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#get_in/2)

```elixir
get_in(list, [Access.all(), :url]
```

Also, the comprehension and pattern matching work well.

```elixir
for %Photos{url: url} <- list, do: url
```

The last, but not the least way would be [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2)

```elixir
list |> Enum.map(& &1.url)
```

---

All the above return *all* urls in the list. To get to the specific one, use [`Enum.at/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#at/3) and/or pattern matching.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your list was a single element list as you quoted, you could pattern match it directly with:

```elixir
[%Photos{url: url}] = list
```

This will put the url into the `url` variable. Example:

```elixir
iex(2)> list = [%Photos{url: "http://localhost:4000/test/img", user: "localhost:4000/test/img/123"}]
[...]
iex(3)> [%Photos{url: url}] = list
[
  %Photos{
    url: "http://localhost:4000/test/img",
    user: "localhost:4000/test/img/123"
  }
]
iex(4)> url
"http://localhost:4000/test/img"
```